# Error in send xml to sever and getting response in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

i am facing a strange issue since last three days….

i am sending an **INSERT** query to server in **XML**, 
it **inserts** record automatically and when i reach to **insertion** code through breakpoints (step by step) it says Duplicate entry (Primary Key) error.

i don't know where it runs automatically, i have set the **breakpoints**, some time it works just perfectly but some time when i reach to insert code through breakpoint that i have set for **very first time**, the query is sent, ran and also the database is updated **itself**,

anywhere the query is being sent twice, and i don't know where this happening all…

this is code how i am working…

Method for sending XML to server

```
-(void) SendXml
{
    myQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MyTable"
           " (cartid, customerid, agentid, ordersubmit)"
           " VALUES ('11', '111', '1111', '1')"];
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
           "<XMLBody>"
           "<Head>"
           "<Document>"
           "<DocType>Query</DocType>"
           "<DocDate>%@</DocDate>"
           "</Document>"
           "<Login>"
           "<UserName>root</UserName>"
           "<Password>#######</Password>"
           "<Database>%@</Database>"
           "</Login>"
           "</Head>"
           "<Body>"
           "<Query>%@"
           "</Query>"
           "</Body>"
           "</XMLBody>",currentDate,myDBName,myQuery];
    URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myseverpath/database.php"];
    Request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [Request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [Request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSError *Error = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@",message);
    uRLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:Request delegate:self];
    if (uRLConnection)
    {
        NSData *XmlFile = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
        ErrorParsing=NO;
        NSString *Data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:XmlFile encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        Xmldata = [Data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        XmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:Xmldata];
        [XmlParser setDelegate:self];
        [XmlParser parse];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection error...");
        NSLog(@"%@",Error);
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    CurrentElement = [elementName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *Element = @"XMLBody";
    if ([CurrentElement isEqualToString:Element])
    {
        ElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Parsing started...");
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
[ElementValue appendString:string];
    if ([CurrentElement isEqualToString:@"myTagName"])
    {
        result = string; // result from XML as how many rows are affected
    }
    else if ([CurrentElement isEqualToString:@"Message"])
    {
        error = string;
    }
    if ([error length] > 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Error" message: error delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [Alert show];
    }
}
```

Please guide me where i am wrong…

Hope you understand my problem, and waiting for swift help … :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why any one not try to answer this question not even any suggestion in comment section. :(

Fortunately i resolve the issue and here i am sharing it.

in above code i just comment out this line

```
//uRLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:Request delegate:self];
```

and change condition as:

```
if (true)
{
    NSData *XmlFile = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
    ErrorParsing=NO;
    NSString *Data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:XmlFile encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    Xmldata = [Data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    XmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:Xmldata];
    [XmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [XmlParser parse];
}
```

now its working perfectly …. :)